# is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, windows, path, subprocess, call

I'm trying to call an external function from Python: the function is vboxmanage.exe and I'm accessing it via subprocess call. The problem is that call cannot find the vboxmanage.exe program, even though it is listed in the path variable. I have tried every possible combination, with path, without path, with listing the full director, without listing the director, but call never finds it: vboxmanage is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Here my questions:

1. For what reason does call disregard my path variable while in the Windows 10 commend prompt the path variable works fine? I'm using shell=True, so this shouldn't happen.
2. Why is it not possible to specify a path of a program and have it executed like that from the command prompt (assuming it's not in path variable). This used to work under DOS a long time ago, but not in Windows 10. I.e. when I type in the command prompt "c:\Program Files....\vboxmanage.exe" it won't find the program. I have to first go into the directory and the execute it.
3. Is there a way to manually navigate into the directory via call command and then invoke a second call command to open vboxmanage.exe?

```
from subprocess import call
param="c:\\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\\vboxmanage controlvm MacBook keyboardputscancode "+h
print (param)
call([param], shell=True)
```

Comment: You have two unescaped slashes in the path. Also, why do you want to use `shell=True`? Whether the Path variable gets used is independent of whether shell is used.

Comment: A list isn't used with `shell=True`, but you don't need that anyway. If you use a list, then all of the command-line elements need to be separate items. This lets subprocess build a command-line string that's escaped following the most-commonly used MSVC `argv` rules.

Comment: For example: `param = [r"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage", "controlvm", "MacBook", "keyboardputscancode", h];` `subprocess.check_call(param)`.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to these folder: `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`  and copy all the files there and then paste them in this folder: `C:\Users\username\VirtualBoxVMs\Ubuntu64` which contains the .VDI files. Then open command prompt and navigate to this folder: `C:\Users\Username\VirtualBoxVMs\Ubuntu64` and run your command from there and it will be recognize.